# Graph coloring algorithm (Greedy coloring)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, graph, greedy

I'm working on a graph-coloring project using Java. I need to implement four different graph coloring algorithms using four-color theorem. I have a problem with one of the algorithms named *few neighbors greedy algorithm*.

I have a map which contains bunch of polygon objects (stored in an arraylist) in it. Also, I have a 2D boolean array that represents the adjacencies of different polygons.

I know the algorithm theoretically: I have a priorityqueue that stores my uncolored polygons. The order of the queue based on adjacency counts. If a polygon has few neighbors, it is considered better than a polygon which has a lot of neighbots. Anyway, the algorithm should repeatedly draw a polygon from the priorityqueue and attemp to color it based on its adjacencies.

Unfortunately, I have problems with the implementation part. I got the priorityqueue based on thie adjacency counts, but I have problems while assigning colors to those polygons. If is there anyone who worked on that kind of algorithms, or anyone with an idea, please share with me. I need some ideas to speed up the implementation part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should state exactly what kind of help you need with the implementation part. "I have problems when assigning colors" how?

A map which contains Polygon objects stored in an array list with a separate 2D boolean array for adjacencies is the input? I assume your polygons are Nodes in the graph.

You should probably build a Graph data structure and navigate it. The classical, C-style approach is using arrays for nodes and edges and [making it look complex](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graphs/edge_array.html).

Since [OOP using Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) naturally generates a [graph of objects](http://static.mockobjects.com/files/mockrolesnotobjects.pdf) that's a good approach to use here.

Graphs are essentially composed of 2 elements: Nodes and Edges.

Start with a Node class. It has a color, an id, and an ArrayList of Edges.
Edges form a relationship between 2 nodes, and may have a weight and a direction.

Make your nodes and edges from the inputs (remember, if a new node doesn't exist, then make it). Then run the [nearest neighbor algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) by picking an unmarked node (a static method may work well for this, or you can *really* practice for real life and implement the Strategy Pattern).

Look out for cycles, though!

Comment: I know, what I wrote above sounds little bit strange and comlicated, but as you can imagine, this is a student project. so, I have some boundries. I cannot use any other libraries or other algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you're trying to color the lowest degree nodes first.  That seems backwards, you should color the highest degree nodes first.  For instance, nodes of degree 3 will always be colorable if you have 4 colors to choose from.

You do realize that any greedy algorithm might very well fail to find a 4-coloring, even if the graph is 4 colorable.

Check out the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring) for some helpful pointers.

Comment: it does not matter if it fails. I need to color the polygons with the chosen algorithm, if algorithm gets stuck, it should halt, and report the count of colored regions.